# How to work around skimage.io.imread() error and re-save image correctly?

Tags: python, scikit-image

The below error is thrown when trying to read the image URL referenced below. (Note, I can't even upload the image to SO because it throws an error when I try to upload it.)

https://s3.amazonaws.com/comicgeeks/comics/covers/large-7441962.jpg

```
image = imread('https://s3.amazonaws.com/comicgeeks/comics/covers/large-7441962.jpg', as_gray=True)
```

This is the stack trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
    return imread(image_or_path, as_gray=True)
  File "skimage/io/_io.py", line 48, in imread
    img = call_plugin('imread', fname, plugin=plugin, **plugin_args)
  File "skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 209, in call_plugin
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "skimage/io/_plugins/imageio_plugin.py", line 10, in imread
    return np.asarray(imageio_imread(*args, **kwargs))
  File "imageio/__init__.py", line 86, in imread
    return imread_v2(uri, format=format, **kwargs)
  File "imageio/v2.py", line 159, in imread
    with imopen(uri, "ri", plugin=format) as file:
  File "imageio/core/imopen.py", line 333, in imopen
    raise err_type(err_msg)
ValueError: Could not find a backend to open `/var/folders/82/rky4yjcx75n1zskhy5570v0m0000gn/T/tmpy9xg7dvb.jpg`` with iomode `ri`.
```

After looking into this further I believe the image was originally a TIFF file that was just renamed to a .jpg file manually, but I'm not sure. If I download the file and try to open it with Photoshop I get the following message.

```
Could not open “large-7441962.jpeg” because an unknown or invalid JPEG marker type is found.
```

If I simply change the extension to a .tiff file it will not open as it states it is an invalid tiff file.

The only way I can open it with photoshop is if I open it with the preview.app and then save a copy of the image as a .tiff file. Then I can open it in photoshop.

This is an issue with a potentially large number of images so re-saving them one-by-one is not an option.

Are there any possible ways to re-save this file when this error is thrown? Or somehow figure out how to handle it even though `imread()` is failing?

Comment: it is a webp image

Comment: @marat thank you. How did you identify that? Do you know of a python library that will open webp images?

Comment: I just checked image properties in a web browser. I believe pillow supports webp images through libwebp

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by using the following.

```
from PIL import Image
from skimage.io import imread

try:
  image = imread(url, as_gray=True)
  return image
except:
  image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
  return image
```

However it is worth noting that when having to make this request using PIL it is significantly slower.